# Add all timestamp data according to date

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have this **access_log** table

```
 create_time  | time_spent
--------------+------------
NOV 02, 2017  | 00:00:00
NOV 02, 2017  | 01:45:04
NOV 02, 2017  | 00:00:00
NOV 02, 2017  | 00:00:00
NOV 02, 2017  | 00:39:29
NOV 02, 2017  | 03:05:49
NOV 03, 2017  | 03:58:57
NOV 03, 2017  | 00:52:29
NOV 03, 2017  | 02:53:25
```

using this table, make looks like this using **PostgreSQL**. it should add all **time_spent** column data of **respective date**

```
 create_time  | time_spent
--------------+------------
NOV 02, 2017  | 05:30:22
NOV 03, 2017  | 07:44:51
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `select create_time, sum(time_spent) from table group by create_time`?

Comment: What data type is `time_spent`?

Answer (score 0):

a simple group by here:

```
t=# create table access_log (create_time  date,time_spent time);
CREATE TABLE
t=# copy access_log from stdin delimiter '|';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself, or an EOF signal.
>> NOV 02, 2017  | 00:00:00
NOV 02, 2017  | 01:45:04
NOV 02, 2017  | 00:00:00
NOV 02, 2017  | 00:00:00
NOV 02, 2017  | 00:39:29
NOV 02, 2017  | 03:05:49
NOV 03, 2017  | 03:58:57
NOV 03, 2017  | 00:52:29
NOV 03, 2017  | 02:53:25>> >> >> >> >> >> >> >>
>> \.
t=# select sum(time_spent), create_time from access_log group by create_time;
   sum    | create_time
----------+-------------
 05:30:22 | 2017-11-02
 07:44:51 | 2017-11-03
(2 rows)
```