# How to calculate total time_spent time between create_time and update_time per day and display according to datewise

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

This is **access_log table**, in this table we have two columns, **create_time** and **update_time**

```
create_time         | update_time
--------------------+------------------
2017-11-02 08:46:14 | 2017-11-02 08:46:14
2017-11-02 05:51:13 | 2017-11-02 07:36:18
2017-11-02 11:42:29 | 2017-11-02 11:42:29
2017-11-02 11:50:28 | 2017-11-02 11:50:28
2017-11-02 05:50:59 | 2017-11-02 06:30:29
2017-11-02 06:19:24 | 2017-11-02 09:25:14
2017-11-03 05:54:17 | 2017-11-03 09:53:15
2017-11-03 07:38:23 | 2017-11-03 08:30:53
2017-11-03 07:38:00 | 2017-11-03 10:31:26
```

Using PostgreSQL, we need to calculate total **time_spent** time between **create_time** and **update_time** per day and display according to datewise.

whereas, **time_spent = update_time - create_time**

```
 create_time  | time_spent
--------------+------------
2017-11-02    | 05:30:22
2017-11-03    | 07:44:51
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47092294/5315974

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add all timestamp data according to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091785/add-all-timestamp-data-according-to-date)

Comment: It is site etiquette to "Accept" an answer it solves (or leads to a solution) all it requires is for you to "click the tick" (it seems an answer below did actually solve this question, so **you should "accept it"**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this :

```
SELECT create_time::date AS day, SUM(update_time - create_time)
  FROM access_log 
 GROUP BY day;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the timestamp columns are of type `timestamp` or `timestamptz`, you can calculate `sum(update_time - create_time)` and group by `date_trunc('day', create_time)`.